# Ssd won't show up

Tags: ssd

I recently bought a 2012 macbook pro retina 15 inch version. The ssd worked perfectly when i bought it and the seller reset the device. When i went home and tried to install the os via internet recovery, the ssd wont show up as available. I tries diskutil liat command and still it wont show up. I plugged in my 32 gb usb drive to check and it showed up perfectly. I then installed catalina on the usb deive and the device turned on but still the ssd isnt available. Could this be an issue with the ssd? I dont have a spare apple ssd to check if it ia an issue with the board.the ssd in question is a sandisk 512gb that came with the laptop.

[image: diskutil list result]

32BG drive is the usb drive that I'm currently using as my boot device.

the disk utility window looks like this:

[image: diskutility window]

Comment: Can you add to your question the results of the terminal command `diskutil list `?

Comment: Can you try extract the ssd and put it in a USB enclosure. If the ssd is ok it's probably a sata cable problem.

Comment: I don't have an enclosure for the specific apple connector. I couldn't find one in the shops nearby. I've ordered one from eBay but It will take around a month to arrive. I also have another m.2 ssd but again I don't have the converter that is used to plug in to the apple port.

Comment: It's a specific ssd? No sata? So it's can't be a sata cable problem. Maybe a ssd broken.

Comment: Thats my thought too. I already have a m.2 ssd with me. So i ordered a converter to plug it into the MacBook. Ill update once it arrive. Hopefully its a faulty ssd.